# Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-1251 JAVA ORACLE

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, oracle

Ola,

Estou tendo um erro quando tento fazer a conexão com um banco oracle.
alguém consegui ajudar.

> codigo

```
private static Connection ObterConexao() {
    Connection conexao = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        try {
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521/xe", "USUARIO", "SENHA");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conexao;
}
```

> Erro

```
GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the 
following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at com.telefonica.DAO.conexao.ObterConexao(conexao.java:25)
at com.telefonica.DAO.conexao.idTiquete(conexao.java:37)
at com.telefonica.CT.Start.upDateSLA(Start.java:33)
at com.telefonica.CT.Start.<init>(Start.java:53)
at com.telefonica.CT.Start$1.run(Start.java:128)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with 
the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10786782/5524514

Comment: Articuno, Eu já havia olhado e não encontrei a solução,porque parece que eles não usam conexao via string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, caso alguem tenha o mesmo.
Estava na URL

Errado

```
conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521/xe", "USUARIO", "SENHA");
```

Certo (A MINHA CONEXAO NÃO USAVA XE E SIM O NOME DO ESQUEMA.

```
conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521/ESQUEMA, "USUARIO", "SENHA");
```